# Why does an alert box keep popping up with the word "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Why does an alert box keep continuing to pop up saying `undefined`?

```
function signup(name, age) {
    if (age < 20) {
        return alert("Sorry " + name1 + "! You are not old enough!");
    }
}

var name1 = prompt("What's your name?");
var age1 = prompt("What's your age?");

alert(signup(name1, age1));
alert("Let me get you started!");
```

Comment: Use the browser developer tools and step through it

Answer (score 2):

On the penultimate line of your script, you alert the return value of `signup`.

Whatever arguments you pass to `signup`, it will return `undefined`

This will either be because it returns the return value of `alert("Sorry" …` (which is always `undefined`) or because the `if` doesn't trigger so `signup` implicitly returns `undefined` (by reaching the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement).

Answer (score 1):

You are alerting and alert with this line `alert(signup(name1, age1));`. Makes no sense. It should be like this:

```js
function canSignup(name, age) {
    return age >= 20;
}

var name1 = prompt("What's your name?");
var age1 = prompt("What's your age?");

if(canSignup(name1, age1)) {
    alert("Let me get you started!");
} else {
    alert("Sorry " + name1 + "! You are not old enough!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can change your code like this

```
function signup() {
    if (age1 < 20) {
        return "Sorry " + name1 + "! You are not old enough!";
    }else{
        return "Let me get you started!"
    }
}

var name1 = prompt("What's your name?");
var age1 = prompt("What's your age?");

alert(signup());
```

you can't return alert in function and `return alert('...')` is wrong 
then you can return  message in function

and `name1` and `age1` is public variable and you can don't send it to function

Answer (score -1):

The function signup will return undefined as you are not handling the condition when age>=20. For any number>=20, signup(name1, age1) will return undefined as your function does not return anything.

```
if (age < 20) {
        return alert("Sorry " + name1 + "! You are not old enough!");
}
```